# String syntax error using javascript's replace function

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, syntax, express

I want to pass an email address as a query string and as such I encode it just before sending it with this line of code:

```
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(email).replace('.' '%2E');
```

Apparently the period shouldn't matter but I keep getting "can't find module 'com' " if i run it that way (I'm coding on node and using express and using a res.render() call)

Don't really understand why in my case periods are causing issues but either way this is the exact error I get:

```
    var encoded = encodeURIComponent(email).replace('.' '%2E');
                                                        ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

Comment: Umm...You don't have a comma...

Comment: "SyntaxError: Unexpected string" *pointing to the string that was unexpected* wasn't clear?

Comment: It's been a long day!! Knew it was referring to there but thought it had to do with weird replace dynamics with .replace or something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Don't really understand why in my case periods are causing issues

It's not the presence of a period. It's the lack of a comma.

```
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(email).replace('.', '%2E');
//                                                 ^ this here
```